# How to control Windows 10 notifications outside of the "Settings" app (specifically, disabling flux notifications)?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, notifications

Flux has an incredibly annoying line of notifications that appear to announce that the app has disabled itself, for whatever reason (when I start some application or use the snipping tool), and I can't seem to find a way to disable them.

Having not found anything in the settings for flux itself or the "Notifications" tab of the Windows "Settings" app (flux doesn't even appear there), I wanted to ask if there is any other way of controlling notifcations and, more generally, what "messages" are allowed to be displayed on the screen (the notifications I speak of are not typical Windows bubble/toast notifications it seems, as they appear close to the upper right corner of the screen and not down at the taskbar).
[image]